# Should I pay back debt to old answers with upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

I have recently started using Stack Exchange with active user accounts after lurking as a reader of Stack Overflow for many years. I am now able to upvote, and considering getting involved in my areas of interest.

My realization: after years as a reader, I have **years** of personal scripts and code projects with developer notes that I wrote in them like:

```
foo = bar(baz); # solved as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234567/
```

My plan is to "pay back my debt" to old Stack Overflow askers and answerers by:

1. searching my hard drives for useful Stack Overflow URLs and noting which were used to solve code problems, e.g.:
   `grep -hiIoRs 'http://stackoverflow.*' .`
2. each day, dispensing most of my upvotes to those linked questions or answers (or both) that helped me in the past.
3. Eventually got "caught up" after a few weeks(?)

In general, I wonder if anyone has ever done something similar. Specifically, I wonder if there are reasons *not* to do this:

1. **Are there public reasons not to do this?** Is upvoting sets of years-inactive questions/answers ever considered harmful to public discussion or the community? (e.g. like necroposting?)
2. **Are there account reasons not to do this?** Would systematically upvoting a list of disparate old answers/questions each day make my account look like a bot that should be suspended or blocked? (Are upvote-bots a thing?)

Comment: You should be fine. Do note that if you happen to upvote many posts by the same person, it *could* be rolled back as "serial voting".

Comment: Interesting. I suspect that won't be an issue at all for my backlog -- it is a mad mix of perl bash python mysql php docker applescript blah blah.

Ironically, that might be an issue once I'm done if I get involved in the Processing tag. KevinWorkman seems to have written 75% of the answers for the language -- if I wanted to provide much feedback on answers there, it will almost always be picking the best of his....

Comment: @Will -- yes, that is *also* true for new URLs in the future, but doesn't answer this question. I have been reading StackOverflow for years; I have been using a voting account for less than a week. This question is about whether / how to address those old useful URLs. Upvoting new ones seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: Kudos for the whole setup: new user posting on meta in a clear way *before* doing something that might be problematic, attributing answers that helped you, and so on. Welcome to SO, and keep it up:) Nice to have you here.

Comment: Your question is specifically about "allowed", so posting a comment, not an answer. Although your plan is awfully nice, I think *there will be many answerers that won't mind at all if you skip it*, more so because most answers you'd revisit are likely to have already received plenty of upvotes. Consider instead spending some time becoming an active asker or answerer: getting even more good content is worth more than extra upvotes :D

Comment: @Jeroen -- Actually, an editor added the word "allowed" to my title. That narrowed my question a bit more than I intended. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I had a weird series of upvotes across a variety of my old answers spread out over a week or two some time back. I wonder if that was a similar situation?

Comment: @KyleStrand if the posts were related, perhaps someone was slowly working their way through a project in your area of expertise...?

Comment: @JeremyDouglass If memory serves, the answers really weren't all that similar--and in fact they were spread across multiple SE sites.

Comment: @KyleStrand Then it sounds more like you had a secret admirer. Especially if they liked your answers in knitting.stackexchange AND snuba.stackexchange....

Comment: Kudos for being one of the probably very few people that attribute code to SO, I don't think many know that technically it's a legal requirement!

Comment: Confused about why a question "can I upvote" would attract so many upvotes and such lengthy discussion. It is well-established that you can upvote anything you want, for any reason, at any time, absent fraudulent or malicious intent.

Comment: This was originally called: "Advice: Pay back debt" etc. -- before an editor rename. I know that I *can*. The question is whether experienced people would recommend if I *should*. To use a related example, in many communities one *can* necropost but generally shouldn't. It isn't always true that "do what thou wilt shall be the whole of the law." Since multiple commenters have been confused I'm adjust the post title from "Am I allowed" to "Should I" to make it more clear.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass is this a research project of yours?  ;-) I noticed that you are an Assistant Professor of English and your area of expertise could suggest something like this.

Comment: @Mr.Radical -- Ha! Only in that *everything* I do is a research project -- in an extended sense.

Comment: Very thoughtful of you to go back into the archives. Given the evolutionary nature of our industry I would be curious if when you revisit older questions if the answer that was "correct" when you used it in your code is still the "most correct" answer today.

Comment: Off topic, but why don’t you use ``grep -R 'http://stackoverflow.com`` instead of that find-xargs-chain?

Comment: Good heavens! A sensible, thoughtful and articulated new user. SO isn't what it used to be 

Comment: Cool idea to make a list of URLS to useful answers. Why didn't I think of that :)

Comment: Remember to vote up useful questions too, not only answers ;).

Comment: @jjmontes -- yes! Rereading I see that my title doesn't fully reflect my plan: "each day, dispensing most of my upvotes to those linked questions or answers (or both) that helped me in the past."

Answer (score 114, accepted):

> 1. **Are there public reasons not to do this?** Is upvoting sets of years-inactive questions ever considered harmful to public discussion or the community? (e.g. like necroposting?)

No, votes don't bump posts to the front page (like necroposting would do). The only person noticing the vote is the one receiving it. So that's not an issue.

> 2. **Are there account reasons not to do this?** Would systematically upvoting a list of disparate old answers each day make my account look like a bot that should be suspended or blocked? (Are upvote-bots a thing?)

Upvoting many answers in a short timespan shouldn't be a problem. But be aware that it is discouraged to vote on too many posts of a single user, which would be detected as targeted "serial voting" and can be reverted, or even get you banned if the mods consider it as "voting fraud".

Answer (score 68):

There would only be an issue if the vast majority of the answers were from one or two users. Then your votes would become indistinguishable from sock-puppet upvotes.

However, if you are voting on other content at the same time, other answers on the same question that answer different aspects of the question for example, then there should be no danger of this.

It's good that you documented the answers that helped you and now you want to reward those answers.

Comment: Please feel free to redact as needed. This thread was not created for sock puppet research.

Comment: I m mostly concerned for the second paragraph of this answer, since ["the exact mechanics are kept secret"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/284349). I haven't seen this info anywhere else. If it is indeed common knowledge, ok.

Comment: @Fermiparadox - I've asked the other SO moderators to take a look at this and no one has raised any concerns.

Answer (score 33):

One possible reason not to do *quite* as you've described is that the answers you used years ago may no longer be the best, even if they were at the time. While there's absolutely nothing wrong with doing lots of voting or with voting on old posts, I'd encourage you to look over all the answers before voting; seeing them all may change your mind about how to vote. It's surprising to me how often new, superior answers can be posted on a question that I thought had already been answered completely thoroughly, often pointing out nuances and flaws in existing answers that I'd never have noticed or thought of.

With that caveat in mind, go ahead.

Comment: This is a helpful caution. Rather than just automatically banging in the votes, I'll also be watching out for things being closed / merged / updated.

Comment: In most cases I still want to give upvotes to the answers *that helped me personally*, as that is the whole point -- unless there is a compelling reason that doing so would be spreading misinformation for future users. Still, I might want to handle the years-old comments (by last file edit) much more cautiously than the ones from the last few months....

Comment: Why not do this: if the answer that helped you personally isn't wrong, upvote; if there's ALSO a better answer that's been posted in the meantime, upvote that as well?

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, that in general, upvoting is encouraged, provided its done within the rules, to the point where you should receive the [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) badge for maxing out your available votes.

As you are probably aware, you will also be [limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/149333) to 40 question votes/ 30 answer votes per UTC day, so you'll need to achieve this over multiple days in chunks of ~30.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whether the owner of the post is active or not, vote for the post not for its owner.
2. Be careful of serial voting ([sock-puppet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets))